# Thread was being aborted with SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, sql-server

I have recently upgraded a custom app to SharePoint 2010.  The same code worked fine with SharePoint 2007.  The error that is being thrown is

> Thread was being aborted.

The stack trace is

> at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )  at
>   SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet,
>   Int32 timeout)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   Namespace.Data.APXData.MapTransactions()  at
>   Namespace.Business.Mapping.MapCancelTransactions()

The code that I'm calling is pretty straight forward.   Here it is:

```
    public static void MapCancelTransactions()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings.conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_MyProc_CANCEL", sqlConn))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 1200; 
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how SharePoint manages the connections, but I suspect something changed from 2007 to 2010.  I am connecting to ta SQL Server 2005 database.

The application works when the stored procedure returns in less than 30 seconds, but when it takes longer, I receive the error.

Is there another time out happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the page was timing out. I had the code working on my development environment, but when I moved it to QA it failed. On my development environment I had the following

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="true">
```

On QA it was set to

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false">
```

Because debug was set to true, it ignores the timeouts in my development environment.

In order to fix on in QA environment, I added to following to the web.config file.

```
<location path="sites/operations/tools/Pages/MyPage.aspx">
   <system.web>
       <httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Once I did that and retested it worked for me!